# Xcode Project Scheme sharing... how to do that?

Tags: xcode

Xcode Project Scheme sharing... how to do that?

When I commit my Xcode project to SVN, I found that the schemes that I created are saved under my username folder, e.g.

abc.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/_my_user_name_.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/projectABC_debug.xcscheme

When multiple users are working on the same project, the schemes can't be shared to them since they don't have the same user name.

So, how to share the schemes among multiple users easily?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

There is a checkbox at the far right "Shared" column in "Manage Schemes" Dialog.

Comment: esbenr at least this question helped P120D1GY out :D

Comment: Does this actually work for you?  I click shared on for a scheme under "Manage Schemes" and the project does not get marked modified and when I finally do make another change to the project and commit it, someone updating or checking it out still does not get the scheme I defined as "shared"

Comment: chadbag, when you add a new shared scheme, XCode creates a new .xcscheme file in the /xcshareddata/xcschemes/. This file remains local to your workspace until you explicitly add it to svn. If you do so, the scheme should be accessible to all users.

Comment: Yes, correct!
You can try this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeShare.html

Comment: But then you have to commit this file `xcschememanagement.plist` which is under your personal folder..

Answer (score 1):

Just an additional hint: if after some manipulations there's still no schemes in Xcode - try to relaunch it. Helped for me with Xcode 7.3.1